# React Native Components disappear on re-render

Tags: react-native

My app has a homescreen built out of hexagons. Since flex doesn't handle diagonal alignment well I used the transform prop to move the hexagons manually into alignment. However, when the app is re-rendered, the hexagons seem to disappear and reappear at random. It usually takes ~8 renders and then the hexagons will all magically reappear.

EDIT: The invisible hexagons can still be pressed, and when the user navigates back to the homescreen, all the hexagons are visible.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }
    render() {
      return (

          <View style={style.columnHexView}>
          <View>
              <TouchableOpacity 
                activeOpacity = {.5} 
                style={style.HexOpacity}
              >
                <Image style={style.Hex}source={require('./images/logo.png')} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          <View>
              <TouchableOpacity 
                activeOpacity = {.5} 
                style={style.HexOpacity}
              >
                <Image style={style.Hex}source={require('./images/emptyhex.png')}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={{transform:([
              {translateY:(Dimensions.get('window').height/10)*-2.5},
              {translateX:(Dimensions.get('window').height/10)*-.84}
            ])}}>
              <TouchableOpacity 
                activeOpacity = {.5}  
                style={style.HexOpacity}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("documentList")}
              >
                <Image style={style.Hex}source={require('./images/documenthex.png')} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={{transform:([
              {translateY:(Dimensions.get('window').height/10)*-3.5},
              {translateX:(Dimensions.get('window').height/10)*.84}
            ])}}>
              <TouchableOpacity 
                activeOpacity = {.5} 
                style={style.HexOpacity}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Settings")} 
              >
                <Image style={style.Hex}source={require('./images/cog.png')} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={{transform:([
              {translateY:(Dimensions.get('window').height/10)*-5}
            ])}}>
              <TouchableOpacity 
                activeOpacity = {.5} 
                style={style.HexOpacity}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("ToDo")}
              >
                <Image style={style.Hex}source={require('./images/todohex.png')}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={{transform:([
              {translateY:(Dimensions.get('window').height/10)*-4.5},
              {translateX:(Dimensions.get('window').height/10)*.84}
            ])}}>
              <TouchableOpacity 
                activeOpacity = {.5} 
                style={style.HexOpacity}
              >
                <Image style={style.Hex}source={require('./images/emptyhex.png')}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={{transform:([
              {translateY:(Dimensions.get('window').height/10)*-5.5},
              {translateX:(Dimensions.get('window').height/10)*-.84}
            ])}}>
              <TouchableOpacity 
                activeOpacity = {.5} 
                style={style.HexOpacity}
              >
                <Image style={style.Hex}source={require('./images/emptyhex.png')}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
      );
    }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  columnHolder: {
    flex: 0,
    height: Dimensions.get('screen').height,
    width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
    backgroundColor: '#424242',
    flexDirection: 'row',

  },
  columnHexView: {
    backgroundColor:'#424242',
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  Hex: {
    aspectRatio: 100/85,
    maxHeight: Dimensions.get('window').height/10,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flex: 0,
    flexWrap: 'wrap'
  },
  hexHold:{

  },
  HexOpacity: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
    display: 'flex',
    maxHeight: Dimensions.get('window').height/5
  }
}
)

export default Home
```

Comment: add code snippet in question

Comment: @MuhammadIqbal added the code, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone sees this, the solution was to use cover resize mode instead of contain. I suspect that it was only rendering some hexagons due to slight overlap in between the hexagons.